# Move the bounty link

Tags: feature-request, bounties, user-interface

Since the change, I've clicked on the bounty link a couple of times, when I meant the comment link, my eyes/hand just automatically go to 'the link at the bottom'. How about putting the bounty link opposite (on the right) rather than below?

Just a thought.

Comment: Ejector seat?  Not really, but still annoying: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html

Comment: Technically, this is the original... but that one can't be closed at the moment due to open bounty. Hmm.

Comment: @Pop & @Cody, hahaha, checkmate :)

Comment: @Cody Gray + @Popular Demand: Actually, I was asking why the bounty button was put somewhere else in the first place. Benjol is asking to actually move it. Those are different questions, even if a single action will resolve them both.

Comment: Billy still wins. His bounty is worth a lot more, and he confirms his question isn't even a feature request! :-)

Answer (score 4):

On the right hand side seems kind of pointless to me...If you *had* to move it so that it wasn't near the comments button, i'd be tempted to move it above the comments onto the same vertical alignment as the user info.

I do see your point though about 'the link at the bottom' because the comment button is the link at the bottom when the bounty link isn't visible...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Done.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Move bounty interface
// @namespace      http://stackexchange.com
// @include        http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    var bounty = [document.getElementById("bounty-link"), document.getElementById("bounty")];
    var lsep = document.createElement("span");
    lsep.setAttribute("class", "lsep");
    lsep.appendChild(document.createTextNode("|"));
    var postmenu = document.getElementsByClassName("post-menu")[0];
    postmenu.appendChild(lsep);
    bounty[0].setAttribute("style", "background-color:white;color:#888888");
    postmenu.appendChild(bounty[0]);
    postmenu.appendChild(bounty[1]);
}());
```

Comment: excellent, now I will write a user script that puts it back. *your move*