# Why is the bounty button in an inconsistent location?

Tags: discussion, design

Why is the button used to start a bounty located below the comment thread, rather than just underneath the question with the other collection of links? This would make it much easier to find, as well as ensure that it appears in the same place on every question, regardless of the length of the comment thread.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: My circles AND arrows have souls this time.

Comment: But not your text!

Comment: @Michael: In my experience if I give my text a soul it rebels and decides to become illegible to everyone, including myself.

Comment: A creative way to show off your "Nice Answer" badge. ;-)

Comment: @Cody: Shhhh... :P (Honestly that was not done on purpose but hey, what the hell :P)

Comment: Related: [Move the bounty link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60196)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/move-the-bounty-link/93604#93604

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it belongs with those links below the tags because starting a bounty is quite a different action than to linking, flagging etc

So I'll point to [my answer to the move the bounty link question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/move-the-bounty-link/93605#93605) *If* it had to be moved