# Can we move "Start a bounty" to a more intuitive location?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, design, bounties, user-interface

[image]

Can we please move the  "Start a bounty" link to be in the same location as all of the other action buttons? It makes no sense to me for this to be buried after the comments - It's an action on the Question. It can be very difficult to locate, especially when your question gets [a lot of comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYvp2.png).

I don't think this should be that difficult to implement - it's just moving the location of a design element. Can we please get this button moved?

Comment: This is one of those requests that's just so plainly head-smackingly obvious once you've pointed it out...

Comment: This is a *fantastic* idea. I'm always searching for a way to add a bounty and most of the time miss it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/why-is-the-bounty-button-in-an-inconsistent-location?rq=1

Comment: Also-related (the question that made me start grumbling about it): http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6389/cannot-create-bounty-bug/ -- I'm almost certain they just missed the fact that it's under the comments...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/move-the-bounty-link

Comment: Not so sure about that. For most users, this is just noise and they don't care what it is and are more interested in the comments.

Comment: @ShadowWizard but for the users who want to set a bounty and don't realize the link is buried after the comments it becomes a UX problem... (and they ask on Meta which makes it *my* UX problem - complaints roll uphill :-D )

Comment: Perhaps a better change would be to make it a first-class UI element (an icon by the voting arrows or something similar - but that's probbaly a lot more UI work than just moving the text link around...

Comment: @mhlester Apparently my search-foo wasn't too strong because it's been head-smackingly obvious to at least 3 other people :-)

Comment: Another idea is always showing the "start a bounty" link, even for new questions, and when clicked it would explain why bounty can't be started. This way much more people will see it, click, and learn about bounties without having to give you UX problems. :)

Comment: I just realized that I upvoted this and it doesn't have a freehand circle.  Am tempted to edit so I can downvote.  And... is that comic sans?

Comment: @Won't It is absolutely ***NOT*** Comic Sans! (It's "Chalkboard" - Apple's version of Comic Sans.) And how do you know I'm not just REALLY GOOD at drawing ovals? :)

Comment: I placed a bounty for the first time recently, and I had to actually look for the button. I expected it to be where it should be.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Please note that a bounty isn't really a good way to attract attention to a feature request for the Stack Exchange team. [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](/a/306398) has better tips that have a higher (if still low) chance of working, but a bounty has a much lower chance of working.

Comment: This was marked as [tag:status-planned] a year and a half ago. Is this actually planned or just set aside and forgotten?

Comment: @Yaakov This feature request was tagged as `status-planned` about 3.5 years ago. Is there any update on this?

Answer (score 22):

Indeed. The current place isn't intuitive and actually causes confusion, also by regular users (like it did with me just now).

The start bounty should be shown in the button bar under a question, and [it should always be visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151395/245360), so it is consistent with all the other buttons:

> [image]

You can debate about its position. I just put it at the end for now. Maybe some extra coloring (the bounty blue) could bring some emphasis on it. I brought back the label to a single word to avoid confusion.

Comment: I like this solution and I think the positioning is much better than its current position

Comment: There's a problem: this link wouldn't show the amount of time left until a question is eligible for a bounty. Currently, the bounty link is replaced by "question eligible for bounty in x hours" for new posts, so your solution wouldn't be convenient to people waiting.

Comment: @SirCumference One possible fix would be to disable the link and show a tooltip with the amount of time left. This is somewhat consistent with the Edit link. Sometimes the Edit link is grayed out and you have to hover over it to get a tooltip to find out why you can't edit.

Comment: @SirCumference Even moving the "start a bounty" button in its current form to be located directly under the "share edit close flag" buttons would be better than what it is now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how it will be done, but the following javascript moves it.

```
var tmp=document.getElementsByClassName("bounty-link")[0].parentNode;tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[1].appendChild(tmp);
```

You can test it to see how it will look, paste this in address bar (your browser must have enabled running js from address bar):

```
javascript:var tmp=document.getElementsByClassName("bounty-link")[0].parentNode;tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[1].appendChild(tmp);
```

And hit <kbd>Return</kbd>. Good? So will wait till devs will do something. (Actually `<div>` with class `bounty-link bounty` should be added to the second `<tbody>`)

Comment: Expecting the end user to work around bad design is not a "solution". Something that requires externally manipulating the page (whether via extensions, userscripts, typing javascript in the URL line, or other means) doesn't solve the problem for casual users, and it is an unrealistic expectation for someone from a non-technical site like [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) to have to have the technical skills to implement such a workaround. (TL;DR: The solution has to work for grandma & grandpa, not the IT department.)

Comment: @voretaq7 I posted this script so as you can see how will it look. I wrote that "I don't know how it will be done".

Comment: ah - as a proof of concept I think it looks OK (though Safari does some unholy things that result in my having TWO links to add a bounty - one above and one below the comments -- I think that's a Safari bug though). My tirade isn't against you but rather against the userscripts-dependence that seems to be increasingly common on the technical Stack sites ("The UI is clumsy? It's fine if you install these userscripts!"), I find it hard to sell people on installing browser scripts to make websites work well...

Comment: @voretaq7 Wait, what Safari are you using? In Safari 7 there is one link. http://i.stack.imgur.com/FGFEY.png

Comment: @voretaq7 test now plz.

Comment: I'm running Safari 7.0.4 - Seems to work properly with that change (but I also restarted Safari which may have something to do with it).

Comment: @voretaq7 Yeah, its because of fixed code. Now works properly. Restarting Safari didn't matter.

Comment: I'm always willing to blame Safari's Javascript engine for problems - it's an endless source of difficulty for one of our webapps here :)

Comment: @nicael I will use your code to make a userscript but you get the bounty for your effort.