# Start Bounty has a different colour

Tags: bug, design

This may be me being silly, but has the `start a bounty` text colour changed?

I distinctly remember it being the same colour as the `add comment` text?

> [image: Bounty different colour image]

Comment: Either a bug or by design, better have a dev take a look and decide.

Comment: This isn't about the bounty dialog, just about the link - tag removed.

Comment: If only it did look like a button, this question would have a bounty I bet.

Comment: I actually think this should be a button, rather than text link,. And be under the "Share" "edit" "close" "flag" links. As it is, under the comments, it seems a bit *lost*.

Answer (score 4):

The colour of the text hasn't changed, instead, the background colour of the box became transparent (happened to the all the SE sites which recently got the new design), but used to be sort of grey:

[image: Bounty text with grey background]

I fully support your request - the background color should be returned, otherwise this link looks... ill.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't dreaming! I looked through every screenshot I have in my SE folder (I keep them all) and didn't find *one* with the bounty text in it!

Comment: @Tim :) And I found it in [this my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234095/can-we-move-start-a-bounty-to-a-more-intuitive-location/234696#comment771731_234696) and cropped. You even suggested an edit on that post, how could you forget? :D

Comment: Wish I has a memory like that :P