# The "start a bounty" button doesn't look like one

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, bounties, user-interface

Currently, the button to "start a bounty" seems to be suffering from Windows 8-syndrome—it looks a bit more like text than an actual button.

> [image]

This issue isn't specific to Meta.SE either—it's a *network wide* problem with the new-style designs.

The old designs had nice little backgrounds around the buttons to make it more clear they were... well... buttons.

> [image]

Can we possibly bring that back?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251760/start-bounty-has-a-different-colour

Comment: @nicael Oops, I somehow missed that one. :(  Must've been the lack of freehand circles.

Comment: @AlexisKing New feature-request needed  - posts with freehand circles out-dupe those without, regardless of age/answers/votes